# dot-onion address for our community

Tags: feature-request

Well, it's a question that was around for a long while but it was not risen so far, so let me be the first :) Why don't we have an onion address for our StackExchange community? It's ridiculous, but we're Tor.StackExchange **without** Tor entrance - even a Facebook has one, aren't we better in it?

Comment: We would still need to be on the clearweb too, so that pure beginners can find us.

Comment: indeed we do need it! But rising an onion entrance is not a mutually exclusive to the onion one - we can have both, and we should

Comment: I think this is a great idea. We can have both a clear web address and an onion address. However, I'm not too sure exactly what the Stack Exchange company thinks on this. After all, it is ultimately their decision to choose whether or not they would create an onion address.

Comment: Well, thechnically - if you're already maintaining a clearnet website - adding Tor and I2P addresses is just rising a darknet daemon and making 1 or 2 lines of configuration, basically that's it! And it's absolutely legal for company - look at Facebook, for example.